# Identify 1-digit nearest neighbors for each row in large matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Assume a matrix of 0s and 1s:

```
library(gtools)
mat<-permutations(n = 2, r = 5, v = c(0,1), repeats.allowed = TRUE)
mat<-cbind(mat, round(runif(nrow(mat)), digits = 2))
```

I would like to go through each row of `mat` and identify its 1 digit nearest neighbors (i.e. all strings that differ by only 1 number) and store the corresponding values of the last column in a separate vector.

At the moment I am using the following code:

```
results <- matrix(NA, ncol = 6, nrow = nrow(mat))
N = ncol(mat)-1
for ( i in 1:nrow(mat)){ #for each row in the matrix
a <- as.vector(mat[i, 1:N]) #select a single row
res <- sapply(1:nrow(mat), function(x) mat[x, 1:N] == a) #cound how many elements match each row
results[i, ]<-c(mat[colSums(res) == N-1, N+1], mat[i, N+1])  #identify those rows that differ max 1 digit and store the value in the last column
}
```

For larger target vectors (i.e. larger `r` in `permutations`), my code takes an immensely long time to run.
Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Perhaps you could make a smaller 'mat' for people to try their code on, rather than the current 32768*16 beast. Cheers.

Comment: ok, I changed to a smaller one. just wanted to use the larger to illustrate how long it takes.

Comment: Can you assume that `mat` contains all bit strings of length `r`?  If so you can explicitly find the nearest neighbors without going through the whole array each time.

Comment: yes mat always contains all possible combinations. so the solution you suggest would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `mat` contains all bit strings of length `r` and is in order, as in the example (if it's not ordered, you can sort it), then you can calculate the indices of the neighbors explicitly without going over the whole array.  For example:

```
m0<-mat[,-ncol(mat)]
bitflips<-diag(ncol(m0))
powers<-2^(ncol(m0):1-1)
neighbors<-t(apply(m0,1,function(x) {sort((powers %*% ((x + bitflips) %% 2)) +1)}))
results<-mat
results[,-ncol(mat)]<-results[neighbors,ncol(mat)]
```